# Should repetitive views be drawn in xml layout or programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an xml activity layout like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
              ....... // around 4 rows per table
           </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>  // around 10 such table
             .
             .
             .
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Each TableLayout  (hence TableRows) contains, similar content. For example in a game app we have level no., score, a progress bar, start button on each row.
My question is, is this the better design to have all the widgets inside the 10 TableLayout **in xml layout** OR I should add the above 10 TableLayout **programatically**.(I need to obtain reference to each widget on the row and set there value). Which is the more efficient and preferred way?

Comment: This is more of a discussion question, and you're not including enough information to give a solid recommendation. If all the rows are the same, a ListView might be more appropriate than a TableView... and you could simply build an Adapter which takes care of displaying each row and keeping track of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my question with the suggestion form 323go and my latest observation.

When the views are being repeated and the data are being fetched from a source like database it is efficient to use a list view.

In my case I had  a LinearLayout and inside that many TableLayout each one related to a level. Inside each TableLayout, data related to score, no. of puzzle solved, progress bar showing the status were there. If I would have used the TableLayout I would have to manage many sets of variables and extra code to rightly populate views with the values.

That's why I used a ListView and set the **TableLayout as the item of the ListView**. I used a custom cursor adapter to bind data with the views.

**TableLayout for showing level related data Before using ListView:**

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
              ....... // around 4 rows per table
           </TableRow>

        </TableLayout> 

        <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
              ....... // around 4 rows per table for score, no. of puzzle solved etc.
           </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>  
             .
             .
             .
             . // around 10 such TableLayout
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**TableLayout for showing level related data after using ListView:**

```
<LinearLayout>
       <TableLayout>
               <TableRow>
                 .
                 .
               </TableRow>   // around 4 rows per table for score, no. of puzzle solved etc.

       </TableLayout>   // only one such TableLayout


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just have an `<include>` tag and give each cell an ID.
For more information: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way would be to do it programmatically. Even if you only have a fixed number of games (10) now, this is something that could easily be read from an external data source. If that happens you may not know how many games you may want to display ahead of time.

If that's the case, it sounds like you're effectively implementing a ListView using a TableLayout. You may want to consider just implementing a ListView instead and save yourself some trouble later on.